# How to make active link underlined (CSS)?

Tags: css, wordpress

I wanted to make a nice underlined menu on website and I found code like below.
It's cool animated but can anyone tell me how to make active link underlined to make visitors sure on which page they are?

````
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.1s, background-color 0.1s;
}
a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 16px 0;
    margin: 0 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: color 0.1s,background-color 0.1s,padding 0.2s ease-in;
    color: #000;
}
a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    transform-origin: right top;
    transform: scale(0, 1);
    transition: color 0.1s,transform 0.2s ease-out;
}
a:active::before {
    background-color: #000;
}
a:hover::before, a:focus::before {
    transform-origin: left top;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}```
````

Comment: `:active` does not mean the same as "current" link. You probably need Javascript for this or some way to identify each page and it's associated link,=.

Comment: [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) means that something is being activated, for example, when you click it.

Comment: You need to find a way to identify and mark your link as being the current page. A good way to do it that improves the accessibility of your page is to add `aria-current="page"` so that screen readers will know that your tab is for the current page. See https://www.digitala11y.com/aria-current-state/

Answer (score 0):

Add a class called "active" to your active a element like so:

```
<li class="active"><a href="index.html">Text</a></li>
```

Then add this to your CSS:

```
a.active{
text-decoration: underline;
}

a.active:hover, a.active:focus, a.active:active{
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: I followed your tips but it didn't help.
Can you check those print screens below?

https://ibb.co/R23qzB7
https://ibb.co/Gt8rSKF

Comment: @MaciejSkoczylas I can't figure out what's wrong with your CSS. So Have a look at this JSFiddle I just made: https://jsfiddle.net/bh5prf2z/ and see if it helps. If not, maybe make a JSFiddle with just your nav bar yourself and share it here, and I'll try my best to help.

Answer (score -2):

I would not do what any other answer says.
(First of all, I'm not a novice WordPress user, but I have experience in CSS)
If you want something along the lines of this:
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1ePl.png)

Then, a span `<span></span>` with nothing in it should do. Then in CSS change the peramiters all you like!

```
   display:block;
   width:100% /*or whatever width you want the effect of <hr>*/
   border-top: 1px solid #ccc'
```

Comment: the OP asked how to make the active link have an underline, but this fails to identify an active link and also doesn't show how do the text decoration